# why does "gedit" doesn't work for reading *.FASTA file?

Tags: gedit

I analyzed my *.fasta file on Linux 16.04. I would like to see the content of the *.fasta file. so I ran below command:

```
gedit SRR662431.fasta
```

the progress of reading content will be started but after a while gedit will be closed and I see the below message in the terminal:

```
(gedit:10466): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_text_line_char_locate: assertion 'char_offset >= 0' failed

(gedit:10466): Gtk-ERROR **: Char offset -2147483648 is off the end of the line
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I appreciate it if you guide me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw, this is rather an bioinformatics question and as such better placed in an appropriate community like https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/.

However, the answer is most likely trivial: Your trying [to view a file of 6.2Gb](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/?term=SRR662431), so your gedit might run out of memory. You may want to try `less`, maybe in combination with `head` and `tail`, in case you really want to go through the raw sequencing reads.